# Get data from website, read and parse the content - ways to improve

Tags: c#, parsing, web, feedback

I made a method that finds synonyms to words using thesaurus.com and I'm looking for comments and feedback to it. In what ways can I improve it, both when it comes to speed, security, reliability (regardless of how "reliable" it is to rely on a third-party website for look-ups), etc.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// This method relies heavily on thesaurus.com for synonym lookups. It is not completely reliable, but is deemed reliable enough in instances where you dont have your own thesaurus
    /// </summary>
    public static string[] GetSynonyms(string word)
    {
        string url = string.Format("http://thesaurus.com/search?q={0}", word);

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            List<string> synonyms = new List<string>();
            StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
            string line;

            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {

                //we know that the synonyms is in the upper-part of the html stream so we do not want to read the entire stream.
                while((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) {
                    var index = line.IndexOf("<span class=\"text\">");

                    if(index > 0) 
                    {
                        index = index + "<span class=\"text\">".Length;
                        synonyms.Add(line.Substring(index).Replace("</span>", ""));
                    }

                    //break when we come to the Antonyms section of the page
                    if (line.Contains("container-info antonyms"))
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return synonyms.ToArray<string>();
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Edit: As an example, it now takes about 3.5 seconds to find the synonyms for the word "old".

Comment: How much of those 3.5s is the network request? How much is your processing time? You can't get down on the network speed, instead you would have to start caching the thesaurus.

Comment: Hm, true... The parsing itself executed in half a second.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @DeeMac: Oh, well, thank you. Wasn't sure where to post this.

Comment: No problem, it's not as busy as SO unfortunately. Not yet anyway, but it's the rightful place for this question.

Comment: @user1021726 I think it's better to use an api, search google for "thesaurus api"

Comment: The question is *far* too broad. Have you even benchmarked your site to see where the bottleneck is? At the moment we would just be shooting in the dark...

Comment: Depending on your execution environment, your could make the method async. other then that, a few micro-optimizations are possible, but they probably won't matter much.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to improve is to use something that is suitable for the job rather than parsing HTML. i.e. a local or webservices API such as

- [WordNet](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/related-projects/#.NET)
- [WordNet C#](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/related-projects/#.NET)

Comment: @user1021726 You are already using someone else's work/algorithms by leeching from thesaurus.com. Check this article for a suitable API: http://www.wynia.org/wordpress/2009/08/a-basic-thesaurus-in-c-with-linq-to-xml

Comment: Use the right tool for the job. Web page scraping is highly likely to break, whereas an API isn't. Often the best way to improve an algorithm is to use another one. as @AhmedKRAIEM said you're already using thesarus.com's algorithm.